# Jmeter: Why increasing number of threads did not change latency?

Tags: jmeter, latency

How is this possible that in Jmetetr increasing number of users (threads) in my test did not changed the latency (Response time)?
I got the same latency for 100 threads and for 300 threads.

Comment: Your question is missing pretty much all information necessary to help you answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have stable network connectivity between JMeter and Application Under Test it is expected that Latency wouldn't change not matter how many threads you kick off. It is "pure" network metric which tells how long did it take for the request to reach to the server.

Check out [How to Analyze the Results of a Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0) article to see the impact of Latency for the end user

Answer (score 0):

**Latency** is the difference between the time when a **request was sent** and time when the response has started to be received.
As per [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the
>   request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the
>   time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as
>   well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general
>   will be longer than one byte. Protocol analysers (such as Wireshark)
>   measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over the
>   interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is
>   experienced by a browser or other application client.

**Response time** (= Sample time = Load time = Elapsed time) is a difference between the time when the request was sent and time when the response has been fully received.

As per JMeter Glossary

> JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request
>   to just after the last response has been received. JMeter does not
>   include the time needed to render the response, nor does JMeter
>   process any client code, for example, Javascript.

So **Response time always >= latency.**

So it is possible that you may have **same Latency** for 100 and 300 threads but Response time will be different or increased.